# Anaconda installation to home directory

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I have set up a SSH connection to a remote server. I want to run some of my python programs on it so am having to download all the modules I had been using.

I just downloaded Ananconda (I don't have root access so installed it in ~) and added ~/anaconda/bin to my PATH. However when I try `import numpy` in Python, it says the module is not found. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

You might be running the wrong version of Python.

To check, use `which -a python`

```
james@bodacious:~$which -a python
/usr/bin/python
james@bodacious:~$
```

In my case, I'm running the version from /usr/bin/python, and that's the only version found in my $PATH. You should see the version from ~/anaconda/bin in your list as well, and for it to be run when you type `python` it needs to be at the top.

If it's not, you can check your $PATH and, if necessary, add `~/anaconda/bin` to the front of it.

```
james@bodacious:~$echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/james/bin
james@bodacious:~$PATH=~/anaconda/bin:$PATH
james@bodacious:~$echo $PATH
/Users/james/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/james/bin
james@bodacious:~$
```

Comment: I didn't realise Anaconda came with a version of Python. I already have a version installed on my system. I only want the numpy module. The version of Python I had been using is installed in `/usr/local_machine/bin/python`. Is it possible to keep using this version along with the numpy module?

Comment: Anaconda is a Python distribution. It doesn't try to dump packages on top of a system Python and hope that things work. Everything needed to run NumPy, including Python itself, is part of Anaconda.

Comment: I didn't realise this when I installed it. In the end I just uninstalled Anaconda and installed numpy seperately.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't any Fedora/Redhat systems handy, but I believe you can:

```
yum install numpy
```

HTH

Answer (score -1):

You've said that all you really want is to be able to use numpy - based on that, using anaconda is probably overkill.

It sounds as though what you're really asking is "Since I don't have root access and can't install system packages, how can I set up a python environment in my home dir that has what I need?"

This sounds like a job for... Super Grover! no wait, I meant virtualenv.

Hopefully your system will already have virtualenv installed for you. If it does, it's fairly simple for you to create your own environment with your own set of packages:

```
james@bodacious:~$mkdir venv/
james@bodacious:~$cd venv/
james@bodacious:venv$virtualenv .
New python executable in ./bin/python
Installing Setuptools..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing Pip.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
james@bodacious:venv$source bin/activate
(venv)james@bodacious:venv$pip install numpy
Downloading/unpacking numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.7.1.zip (3.1MB): 3.1MB downloaded
```

Once that completes, you'll have your own copy of numpy which you can access in this environment just by using `cd venv; source bin/activate` to set your $PATH and $PYTHONPATH to point at your custom install.

If you don't already have `virtualenv` installed things get more tricky....

Comment: Anaconda is only overkill in the sense that it comes with a lot of packages that you don't need, but you can easily remove them, or start with a [Miniconda installer](http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/index.html), which only includes the basics that you need to install packages like numpy.